# Why are self-deleted posts not shown in the 10k Tools?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, 10k-tools, deleted-posts, self-delete

I noticed on [Retrocomputing](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/439/621) that self-deleted posts do not show up in the Deleted section of the 10k Tools.  Why is this?  It seems like it would be useful to have all deleted posts show up in this list.

Comment: Self deletion is the #1 cause of deletion on SO...

Answer (score 26):

I agree.  Moderators can access a list of self-deleted posts, but as a moderator I want the *community* to be watching over deletions, not just mods.  10k users would be able to see those posts if they had the links, and we give them a tool to review *other* deletions.  So why not include self-deletions in the 10k deleted-posts list?  I don't see a way that this can hurt, and it can help the community share the moderation work.

Answer (score 5):

I assume Stack Exchange does not want to "shame" users.

Suppose one wrote a REALLY dumb question or answer, then realised it's bad seconds after posting, and deleted it. While it will always be there, visible to 10k users who happen to visit the question, I think it's better not to spread the shame.

So, I do agree with this behavior.

---

However, with some tweaks it can be made even better:

1. If the post was self deleted X hours after being posted, do show it in the 10k tools.

   or
2. If the post had at least one upvote when deleted, do show it in the 10k tools.

This way we can monitor possible good posts being self deleted.

Comment: Yes,it would be shame when 10k users see dumb post. Agree!

Comment: In theory, 10k+ users would be the mods. Once they were called as "community moderators", differentiating them from the "diamond moderators", what we call now only mods. Unfortunately, the privilege system is inflated a little bit since then, making the 10k+ too little advancement compared to the effort required to reach it. Thus, on the original reasons, I think yes, the mods (in its original sense) should see all deletion events.

Comment: What about on Metas?  I think that on metas with lower activity, any deleted post should be shown in the 10k tools.

Comment: @JAL good point about meta sites, but still, same argument holds true - people can make silly mistakes so they self delete.

Comment: But it's not like you can _easily_ stumble across these "dumb" questions (or answers). And you only see the last 7 days by default (30 days max). When I'm looking through the deleted posts list I'm generally looking for a specific post, I'm not casually browsing. I don't really see why you would provide access to deleted posts for 10K+ users when it is going to be further moderated? (Even "trusted users" 20K+ can't see these self-deleted posts.)

Comment: I've seen this scenario played out a few times... user asks ambiguous question that gets several comments seeking clarification. User later deletes the question (I'm _assuming_) and re-asks the same question... process starts over. I'm sure I commented on the original question, but there is no record in my comment history and there is no deleted question with a similar title in the deleted posts section of the mod tools. "Eh?", I'm thinking. I can't see how the comments on the original question played out. Mods seem to have missed it as they did not see the original question.

Comment: @MrWhite still, my stand holds. What you describe (users re-posting questions) is abuse of the system, such users should be reported and suspended by moderators, after a warning.

Comment: You can also use the browser history to locate a post that you have seen before (if you're on the same device). But I agree that it would be better if they just show up in the 10k tools, I don't think there is any "shaming" involved here.