# How should we handle a post with NSFW contents that was deleted by owner right after posting it?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, etiquette, offensive

I just saw an answer with highly [NSFW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_safe_for_work) content, that was deleted by its owner shortly after being posted, before it even gathered any downvotes.

Of course that while not deleted we should flag those as "rude of abusive", but since it's deleted it's not possible any more, only to use custom moderator flag.

So what should we do with such posts? Should we flag anyway and ask moderators to send warning to the author, or just edit the NSFW content out and move on?

Comment: I redacted the NSFW image from the revisions.

Comment: @Oded Another small question: Can mods edit rev history? Or only SE staffs can?

Comment: @iBug moderators can redact revisions too for a while.

Comment: @iBug technically, there are two moderators necessary; one to create the redaction, another one to approve it.

Comment: Related: [Should I do anything about self-deleted spam?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/294576/307988)

Comment: @Cai thanks! Somehow I missed that!

Comment: @Sha can you edit the contents on a self deleted post?

Comment: @Err I don't think so. Why you ask?

Comment: The last sentence _or just edit the NSFW content out and move on?_

Comment: @Err oh sorry, meant in my last comment that only OP can't edit post they deleted, regardless of reputation. Other 10k users can edit as usual. (that is what I did in the specific case too.)

Answer (score 3):

It *is* probably a good idea for moderators to be aware of the issue - though how best to deal with it really depends on why it was deleted - if its an oopsie, it might be no foul, but OP may choose to undelete it with the content in future. The mods (or others - as seems to be in this case) may choose to redact, mod message or otherwise deal with the issue. For a user with a history of this, we'd also have a audit trail.

So custom flag, mentioning the "NSFW-ness", and that should be sufficient. The fact that it *is* deleted, is sufficient for this anyway.

Comment: Well, in the specific case that sparked my question, it was answer to a question about Hot Network Posts, so my guess is that the author was trying to joke by posting "hot" picture, then realized it's improper and deleted.

Comment: Well, in this case, its an "oops". Still - its worth the mods knowing, in case IMO. and ugh, infantile humour.

Answer (score -1):

**TL;DR** Skip directly to the last paragraph.

If there's a minor amount of NSFW content, edit it out if possible. If you think the post is not salvageable via editing, flag it as *rude or abusive*.

Of course NSFW content is abusive, so quoting the FAQ:

> If an **otherwise valid** post contains vulgar words as an expression of frustration, edit the bad part out instead of flagging the entire post as *rude or abusive*.

On a high traffic site (SO, SU, SF, EL&U, MSE) the post won't survive long before it receives 6 red flags. On other sites... flag for ♦ attention.

Even if the OP has deleted the post by himself, you can still flag for a ♦ to prevent the OP from undeleting it, further ensuring the inappropriateness won't "resurrect". Then only 10k's and ♦s can voluntarily see it.

Comment: Sorry, but answer is not relevant. Whole discussion here is about **deleted** posts which can't be flagged as abusive.

Comment: You can still flag for ♦ attention.