# Which deletions are not shown in 10k-tools? Are posts deleted by roomba shown there?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, 10k-tools, auto-delete

As I learned from some other discussions, self-deleted posts are not shown in moderator tools [available to 10k+ users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools). For example: [Why are self-deleted posts not shown in the 10k Tools?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292531)

Are there some other deleted posts which are omitted from delete tab in 10k-tools? Specifically, if a question is [auto-deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/roomba), will it be shown there?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Auto-deleted questions are shown. These are all from the “Recently Deleted” list:

[image]
[image]
[image]

We can see posts deleted from spam flags are shown and roomba deleted `RemoveAbandonedClosed` and `RemoveMigrationStubs` posts are shown.

Posts *aren't* shown if the user account that owns that post is deleted (so spam posts are only shown until the account is deleted for example).

Self-deleted posts aren't shown either, ♦ moderators do have a separate list of self-deleted posts available to them though.

*Note, there are a few other roomba states I couldn’t find (I assume because there hasn’t been any recently; the last rejected migration was too far back to appear in the list for example) but I wouldn’t expect they’re any different. I will update this when possible.*

Comment: I believe that posts deleted by their author are also not shown.

Comment: @Sha sure, that was already mentioned in the question :) updated the answer though