# Question with vote to undelete isn't visible in 10k tool

Tags: support, bug, deleted-questions, 10k-tools, vote-to-undelete

I have a roomba-deleted [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/395549/339911) with an active vote to undelete:

> [image]

I'm expecting to see it in the list of questions with undelete votes in [10k tools page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tools?tab=Delete&daterange=last30days). But for some reason I don't see it:

> [image]

From my PoV it's a bug, but probably there are some explanations behind that?

Comment: Is that post in the Most votes table when you expand it? How many posts are there that need 2 votes to undelete? There are only two slots in that block you circled.

Comment: @rene The question also doesn't appear when [restricting the view to the last 7 days](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtmPV.png). The undelete vote is [from 2 days ago](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSBxJ.png).

Comment: That's interesting. According to the answer here, auto-deleted questions are shown among the recently deleted: [Which deletions are not shown in 10k-tools? Are posts deleted by roomba shown there?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/301539) (So I would expect the logic to be the same in other places.)

Comment: @rene there's no to expand in "undelete votes" section. Only two items at all. No "rectangle" icon next to them.

Comment: Looks like a job didn't run that should populate those stats.